# Getting cumulative grand total in JSON+PHP?

Tags: php, json

My fetch code is:

```
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {
        array_push($result, array(
            'product_id' => $row[1],
            'name' => $row[6],
            'image' => $row[9],
            'amount' => (is_null($row[8]) ? '' : $row[8]),
            'qty' => (is_null($row[2]) ? '' : $row[2]),
            'subtotal' => number_format($row[2] * $row[8])
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

Is there a way for me to send the results to my frontend (PHP) to display the cumulative grand total of all subtotals tallied?

What I am trying to achieve is something along the lines of this:
(PSUEDO CODE) 'grandtotal' => 'subtotal' += 'subtotal' ** this obviously doesnt work inside... but I am trying to total up the subtotals and have a cumulative grand-total at each point in the array.

In my front end (PHP) I use .append to code i.e. using codes like:  "+this['product_id']+" Any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Use mysqli_*

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `SUM(subtotal)` in your query as another column if possible, or simply loop the results and add the totals in PHP afterwards before encoding it to JSON.